# Flutter - how can I get the ids and the values separately but respectively

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make an attendance app and I have a list of students with their on switch and what I thought would work was to get the values of the switches if the student is absent or not but when I try to get the ids of the students and the values they come out together

```
RaisedButton.icon(
                 shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                 label: Text(
                   'Submit',
                   style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                 ),
                 color: Color(0xff2fbd9f),
                 icon: Icon(
                   Icons.add,
                   color: Colors.white,
                 ),
                 onPressed: () {
                   var keys = switchStates.keys;
                   var values = switchStates.values;
                   print("$keys $values");
                 },
               ),
```

this is the button that is clicked and the print out puts `flutter: (001121804, 001121821, 001121838) (true, false, true)`
but I want to set the id as a field and the boolean as a value

This is a screen shot which I created in firestore manually
[image: This is a screen shot which I created in firestore manually]

Comment: Your question is not so clear. You want something like on the Firebase sheet at the right ?

Comment: yes you are right and thank you for replying fast I have been trying to figure this out for almost a week now

Comment: Check my answer below

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for.  What output do you want?

Comment: @jamesdlin I just want to put the id as a field and the boolean as a value

Comment: Then why do you want separate lists of keys and values?

Comment: @jamesdlin to put it to firestore

Answer (score 0):

You must iterate over your `switchStates` records as following

```
onPressed: () {
   List keys = [];
   List values = [];

   switchStates.forEach((key, value) {
     keys.add(key);
     values.add(value);
   });
   
   // add this to see what you expect
   for(int i = 0; i < keys.length; ++ i) print("${keys[i]} : ${values[i]}");
}
```

Comment: `the method 'add' isn't defined for the type 'Iterable'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'add'.` I am getting this error

Comment: Maybe I have not been clear. You must do this in your onPressed method

Comment: I think this is working how do I set it to firestor?

Comment: the out put is good when I print it {001121804: true, 001121821: true, 001121838: true}

Comment: Check my last edit. If you want to iterate over it

Comment: ```flutter: 001121804 : false
flutter: 001121821 : true
flutter: 001121838 : false
``` here is. the output

Comment: Is not this you want ?

Comment: I see no advantage here for using `keys.add`/`values.add` over using `keys = switchState.keys` and `values = switchState.values`.

Comment: @jamesdlin OP said `how can I get the ids and the values separately but respectively`. So your line does not answer that

Comment: Give a better answer and stop disturbing

Comment: Assuming that `switchStates` is a `Map`, I forgot that `Map.keys` and `Map.values` return `Iterable`s and not `List`s.  Using `keys = switchStates.keys.toList()` and `values = switchStates.values.toList()` would be cleaner.  Or just iterate over `switchStates.entries` if the separate `keys` and `values` lists aren't actually needed.

Comment: The keyword `respectively` in his question is joke to you ?

Comment: so.how do I actually put it in firestore

Comment: @dm_tr it is what I want but can you tell me what to do next